# How do use Rpc in unity photon (script not working)

Tags: photon

Here I made a simple flashlight script in unity photon multiplayer using RPC the script set active and false the game object FlashLight. When I run the game I seem to be getting no errors in the console. Anyway, 2 clients are not syncing the FlashLight changes

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;

public class flashlight : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public GameObject FlashlightLight;
    private bool flashlightActive = false;
    PhotonView view;
    public GameObject player;
    //public bool active;



    void Start()
    {
        view = this.GetComponent<PhotonView>();

    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void Light(bool active)
    {
        if (view.IsMine)
        {

            if(active == true)
            {
                FlashlightLight.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }

            if(active == false)
            {
                FlashlightLight.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }


        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            view.RPC("Light", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, true);
            
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            view.RPC("Light", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, false);
        }
        
        
    }


    

}
```

Comment: - I would not buffer the RPC calls.
- `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` already includes `photonView` reference.
- Maybe the light state should be a room or player property and use `SetCustomProperties` instead of RPC?
- The code could be cleaned up and optimized in fewer lines.

Answer (score 0):

In your RPC method `Light()` you are checking for the `isMine` property and setting state of light only if it is local player.

You have to remove the condition `if(view.isMine)` from `Light()` and put it into `Update()` where you are checking for player input to make it work.

Something like following would work just fine

```
    [PunRPC]
    public void Light(bool active) {
        FlashlightLight.gameObject.SetActive(active);
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (!photonView.IsMine)
            return;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)) {
            photonView.RPC("Light", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, true);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G)) {
            photonView.RPC("Light", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, false);
        }
    }
```

However your code can be further optimized like, instead of using `view` variable you can just use `photonView` property which is inherited in your class via `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` calls.